# how to detect idle time from keyboard and mouse in TCL/TK

Tags: linux, tcl

I have a tcl/tk application, that would go log out the user in the current tcl application out. I need to find out the current idle time for the user that is currently log in.

I try to use 'w' command but that is for something else, i guess. I'm working on linux environment by the way

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the `tk inactive` command (see https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TkCmd/tk.htm#M8) available in Tk 8.5 and newer.

It might be what you need. It is the implementation of TIP 245 (http://www.tcl.tk/cgi-bin/tct/tip/245.html).

Comment: i try that but always returns -1 :( i guess is not supported in my system

Comment: Probably not supported, have a look at the TIP, it lists the needed X11 libraries (libXss and libXext) to support it, so make sure those are installed.

Comment: I know I have the libXss, whats the package name of libXext to install it ..?